# What does $T0 mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

When programming in Swift, sometimes I see error messages containing `$T0`, `$T1`, `$T2`, etc.  It seems like they have something to do with closures.

This code works fine:

```
let test = { (argument: Int) in
    println("Argument is \(argument)")
}

test(42)
```

Xcode's autocomplete tells me that the type of `test` is `(Int) -> ()`, so the return type appears to be inferred.

But if I add a `return` statement to the closure:

```
let test = { (argument: Int) in
    println("Argument is \(argument)")
    return
}

test(42)
```

I get an error saying:

```
error: cannot convert the expression's type '(Int) -> (Int) -> $T0' to type '(Int) -> (Int) -> $T0'
```

What does `$T0` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T0 refers to an anonymous, or unknown type, generally speaking, if you see it, it means that the type inference failed and you can eliminate the problem by being more specific about typing.

In the specific case you refer to, the issue is that the compiler currently has problems resolving types for closures, particularly when they have return statements and no explicit type.   To get your example to work (maybe you want a return in the middle of a block) you can be explicit about the return type:

```
let test = { (argument: Int) -> Void in
    println("Argument is \(argument)")
    return
}
```

(Note: apparently Swift 1.2 fixes several major classes of similar bugs)